# request with multiple id Symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got an array of IDs and I'd like to get an entity array from my IDs array.

I can't use find.

The sql request looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 12 OR id = 10 ...
```

with a loop on my id array.

Comment: Are the entities mapped? Because if you are planning raw sql you will be have a bad time

Answer (score 38, accepted):

How about using the QueryBuilder class:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('m');
$qb->from('MyEntity', 'm');
$qb->where($qb->expr()->in('m.id', array(12, 10)));

//ArrayCollection
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Or DQL:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT m FROM MyTable m WHERE m.id IN(12, 10)');
```

Comment: Just a side note to OP: Beware that if you're supplying dynamic array to `QueryBuilder` to test if it's empty. Empty `SQL` `IN()` expresion results in error.

Answer (score 104):

You can also get it directly from repository:

```
$em->getRepository('YourRepo')->findById(array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Also you can pass parameters in get no tin array, but in simple string glued by commas

```
?ids=1,2,3,4,56
```

And after that get it from $request

```
$em->getRepository('YourRepo')->findById(explode(',', $request->get('ids'));
```

Comment: findById() does not exist

Comment: @Ayk It is a dynamic function that doctrine matches to the `id` column. If your key column is called `table_name_id` the function would be `findByTableNameId`.

Comment: I don't like to use magic things - so you can do it `->findBy(['id' => $idsArr)` this will give you what you want

Comment: Worth to mention that with the magic method, the order of the id's is kept in asc order. If you give another order e.g 4,3,2,1 ... the query will return them anyway as 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 27):

In case you don't want to use magic methods, instead of using this working piece of code:

```
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:FooEntity')->findById([1, 2, 3]);
```

...you can use this:

```
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:FooEntity')->findBy(['id' => [1, 2, 3]]);
```

Effect is the same.

Comment: What's the actual superstition against magic methods? Am I missing something?

Comment: @baldrs, PHPStorm for example reports such method call as nonexistent. You have to then either suppress inspection for such statement or provide some PHPDoc comment. Given that, I prefer just write the method. Easier to refactor later as well.

Answer (score 20):

Simply use:

```
$em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->findById(array(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Arrays are supported as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use with the Entity class:

```
$em->getRepository(Entity::class)->findById($ids); //$ids is array
```